# How to store data from XML in SQL server.

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, xml, c#-4.0

I have a url in xml format.

Sample **xml file** format is as following:

```
            <shows>
            <show>
                <eventID>10025</eventID>
                <name>MARCH Barrel</name>

                <ticketURL></ticketURL>

                    <venue>
                        <venueID>3648</venueID>
                        <name>Double Barrel</name>
                        <address>3770 Las Vegas Blvd. South</address>
                        <address2></address2>
                        <city>Las Vegas</city>
                        <state>NV</state>
                        <zipcode>89109</zipcode>
                        <country>US</country>
                    </venue>
                      </show>
                </shows>
```

**Question:**
How, is it possible to store venueID & name in sql server 2008 using C#, as I have a table which contain this type of field ?

Comment: this xml is generated by a url. How to get the xml data in dataset or something. & then store only id & name in database

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005 and up have a datatype called "XML" which you can store XML in - untyped or typed with a XSD schema.

You can basically fill columns of type XML from an XML literal string, so you can easily just use a normal INSERT statement and fill the XML contents into that field.

OR

You can use the function OPENXML and stored procedure sp_xml_preparedocument to easily convert your XML into rowsets.

EDIT: Try This

```
String xmlFile = @" <shows>
            <show>
                <eventID>10025</eventID>
                <name>MARCH Barrel</name>

                <ticketURL></ticketURL>

                    <venue>
                        <venueID>3648</venueID>
                        <name>Double Barrel</name>
                        <address>3770 Las Vegas Blvd. South</address>
                        <address2></address2>
                        <city>Las Vegas</city>
                        <state>NV</state>
                        <zipcode>89109</zipcode>
                        <country>US</country>
                    </venue>
                      </show>
                </shows>";


                DataSet ds = ConvertXMLToDataSet(xmlFile);

            foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                //get Your Tables here
            }
```

and Method:

```
public static DataSet ConvertXMLToDataSet(string xmlData)
            {
                StringReader stream = null;
                XmlTextReader reader = null;
                try
                {
                    DataSet xmlDS = new DataSet();
                    stream = new StringReader(xmlData);
                    // Load the XmlTextReader from the stream
                    reader = new XmlTextReader(stream);
                    xmlDS.ReadXml(reader);
                    return xmlDS;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (reader != null) reader.Close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.Look i have a url which consist of this type of xml. First thing is how do i get all these value in a dataset so that i choose the data which i want to store in data base.

Comment: Getting this error :- 
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: ' ', hexadecimal value 0x03, is an invalid character. Line 3854, position 34.

Comment: see a sample code 
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader("http://news.yahoo.com/rss/");
            DataSet ds = new DataSet(); in this way i got news feed  from yahoo now similarly i want my xml url return data in dataset or something to hold it & then i split the data according to my need to store it to database
            ds.ReadXml(reader);
            grid.DataSource = ds;
            grid.DataBind();

Comment: Your Question was not about that.Now You want To Do Different Thing.I did it what you want to say

Answer (score 0):

You can store information in SQL Server XML type field. Following article contains complete information for how to use XML datatype in sql server.

https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/working-with-the-xml-data-type-in-sql-server/